# Linking to the next recommended Product based on stock availability

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables that I need to link together but the output needs to consider switching to the second-best alternative in instance that the best recommended product is out of stock.

Here's the first table, which keeps the record of the chemical stock:

[image: Chemical Stock]

Then here's the second table which contains the trial scheme and outlined the best chemical fit, second-best, and third-best alternative for each sample:

[image: Trial Scheme]

And finally, here's the desired output which will recommend product application based on availability of stock in each bottle.

[image: Recommendation List]

The record highlighted in red is just to show where the recommendation needs to switch to second-best alternative because we ran out of stock in Product A.

Any help or input would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This calls for a VBA solution IMO. Read table1 into an array, then loop table2. It's not really suited for SQL.

Comment: As @Andre points out, you will need some kind of looping situation, because it looks like you want to essentially "consume" available stock as the results output is being generated, so that everything that needs chemical "Product A" doesn't just always come up with "A01".  Since you're wanting to do this within Access, a VBA solution is the likely best approach.  Of course, the primary purpose of StackOverflow is to help you with issues that you're having with your own code - not to just write your solution for you.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your comment, as much as possible I'm trying to do this with query. But I'll try tinkering around with it a bit and I will try the answer given by Erik below as well. If it's not possible, I will look into solving it with VBA as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your second table is not normalized, which makes writing queries against it difficult. Any time you have columns named 1/2/3, that's a strong indication you're not normalizing, limiting what the database can do and making it difficult for yourself.

Start by normalizing it, and store that in a separate query. Most RDBMSes have an `UNPIVOT` query to normalize, but Access only has `UNION` to do so.

**qryTable2Normalized**

```
SELECT Sample, BestChem1 As Chem, 1 As Position
FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT Sample, BestChem2 As Chem, 2 As Position
FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT Sample, BestChem3 As Chem, 3 As Position
FROM Table2
```

Really, this should be a third table, though, since if we store it in a separate table we can easily have a fourth best, sixth best, 100th best, etc.

Then, you can select the chemical with the lowest position using an ordered subquery.

```
SELECT Sample, (
   SELECT TOP 1 BottleCode
   FROM Table1 t1 
   INNER JOIN qryTable2Normalized t22 On t1.Chemical = t22.Chem 
   WHERE t22.Sample = t2.Sample AND t1.Stock <> 0 
   ORDER BY t22.Position ASCENDING
) As Recommended
FROM Table2 t2
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to construct some logic for your query.

I would break this down into different parts.
First I would take in the consideration of the max stock that is available for each product.

```
Select chemical, sum(stock) from chemical_table
group by chemical;
```

Next I would assign a number to each product available to help us with recommendation.

```
with product_order as
(Select chemical, bottlecode, stock , 1 as num
from chemical_table
union all
select chemical, bottlecode,stock, num+1
from product_number
where num < stock)
select * from product_number;
```

Next, I would look at sample_table to do running totals for each chemical product for all the three options.

```
Select 
sample 
,bestChem1
,count(bestChem1) over (partition by bestChem1 order by sample between current row and unbounded preceding ) as requirement_bestChem1
,bestChem2
,count(bestChem2) over (partition by bestChem2 order by sample between current row and unbounded preceding ) as requirement_bestChem2
,bestChem3
,count(bestChem3) over (partition by bestChem3 order by sample between current row and unbounded preceding ) as requirement_bestChem3
from sample_table;
```

Now, I can compare max available stock against each sample and add case statements to go for the recommendation using the above results in cte.

```
--single row max product availability
with cte_availability_chemical as
(select * 
from
(
select chemical, stock from chemical_table
)t
pivot(
sum(stock)
for chemical in ('ProductA', 'ProductB', 'ProductC')
) as pivot_table)
,

-- there are 5 stocks of product A, this cte produces 5 records for the product for the same bottlecode which has more than 1 stock
with product_order as
(Select chemical, bottlecode, stock , 1 as num
from chemical_table
union all
select chemical, bottlecode,stock, num+1
from product_number
where num < stock)
select chemical || num as product_number, bottlecode from product_order,

-- provides a count for each time a product has been used a bestChem
cte_sample_requirement as
(Select 
sample 
,bestChem1
,count(bestChem1) over (partition by bestChem1 order by sample between current row and unbounded preceding ) as requirement_bestChem1
,bestChem2
,count(bestChem2) over (partition by bestChem2 order by sample between current row and unbounded preceding ) as requirement_bestChem2
,bestChem3
,count(bestChem3) over (partition by bestChem3 order by sample between current row and unbounded preceding ) as requirement_bestChem3
from sample_table),

--simple cross join maintaining the same number of rows as previous cte
cte_recommedation_calc1 as
(Select 

csr.*,
cac,*

from cte_sample_requirement csr
cross join cte_availability_chemical cac),

--assign a product number to the qualifying available product number
cte_recommendation_calc2 as
(select 
sample,
case 
    --check for bestChem1 availability
    when bestChem1 == 'ProductA' and requirement_bestChem1 <= ProductA
    then 'ProductA' || requirement_bestChem1
   
    when bestChem1 == 'ProductB' and requirement_bestChem1 <= ProductB
    then 'ProductB' || requirement_bestChem1
    
    when bestChem1 == 'ProductC' and requirement_bestChem1 <= ProductC
    then 'ProductC' || requirement_bestChem1
    

    --check for bestChem2 availability    
    when bestChem2 == 'ProductA' and requirement_bestChem2 <= ProductA
    then 'ProductA' || requirement_bestChem2
    
    when bestChem2 == 'ProductB' and requirement_bestChem2 <= ProductB
    then 'ProductB' || requirement_bestChem2
    
    when bestChem2 == 'ProductC' and requirement_bestChem2 <= ProductC
    then 'ProductC' || requirement_bestChem2
    

    --check for bestChem3 availability    
    when bestChem3 == 'ProductA' and requirement_bestChem3 <= ProductA
    then 'ProductA' || requirement_bestChem3
    
    when bestChem3 == 'ProductB' and requirement_bestChem3 <= ProductB
    then 'ProductB' || requirement_bestChem3
    
    when bestChem3 == 'ProductC' and requirement_bestChem3 <= ProductC
    then 'ProductC' || requirement_bestChem3

end as product_number
from cte_recommendation_calc1),

cte_recommendation as 
(
select rec.sample,
ord.bottlecode
from cte_recommendation_calc2 rec
left outer join product_order ord on rec.product_number = ord.product_number
)
select * from cte_recommendation;
```

There can be further optimisations steps and deductions to the above.